# В WPF при наведении на кнопку появляется стандартный голубой цвет

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

В WPF при  наведении на кнопку появляется стандартный голубой цвет, в винде 10 скорее всего другой. Если я убираю галку с параметра IsHitTestVisible то кнопка перестаёт реагировать на все мои дальнейшие действия. Вообще я хотел при наведении на кнопку менять background но из за этого голубого цвета я просто не вижу своего бэкграунда. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Используйте `Simple Styles.xaml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед тем как задавать какие либо атрибуты, прочитайте про них.

MSDN:

> Действительное значение этого свойства влияют относительные позиции
>   поддерживающих проверку нажатия элементов в логическом дереве.
>   Например, если элемент является дочерним элементом элемента элемент,
>   который является не попадания видимым, действительное значение
>   свойства для дочернего элемента останется false, даже при попытке
>   задать это значение локально. По этой причине важно не задавать
>   IsHitTestVisible для false в составном элементе управления, если
>   только не требуется никаких входных данных или попадания для данного
>   элемента управления. Дополнительные сведения о проверки нажатия см. в
>   разделе нажатия на визуальном уровне.

Для того что бы унифицировать стили на всех ОС не достаточно просто менять фон у элементов, вам необходимо написать набор стилей, воспользуйтесь базовыми шаблонами, которые можно найти на MSDN.

Так же можно воспользоваться уже готовыми реализациями, которых на просторах интернета полно.

Для наглядности, вот вам один из стилей, результатом будет:

[image]

```
<!--#region Default Colors-->
<Color x:Key="MouseOver.Background.Color">#FFF2F2F2</Color>
<Color x:Key="MouseOver.Border.Color">#FFA8B0C2</Color>
<Color x:Key="MouseOver.ForegroundHoverColor">#FF696C74</Color>

<Color x:Key="Focus.Background.Color">#FFEDEDED</Color>
<Color x:Key="Focus.Border.Color">#FF818DA7</Color>
<Color x:Key="Focus.Foreground.Color">#FF696C74</Color>

<Color x:Key="Pressed.Background.Color">#FFEDEDED</Color>
<Color x:Key="Pressed.Border.Color">#FF818DA7</Color>
<Color x:Key="Pressed.Foreground.Color">#FF696C74</Color>

<Color x:Key="Static.Background.Color">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
<Color x:Key="Static.Foreground.Color">#FF696C74</Color>
<Color x:Key="Static.Border.Color">#FFBDC3D1</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Static.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Static.Background.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Static.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Static.Border.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Static.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Static.Foreground.Color}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOver.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource MouseOver.Background.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOver.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource MouseOver.Border.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOver.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource MouseOver.ForegroundHoverColor}" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Pressed.Background.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Pressed.Background.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Pressed.Border.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Pressed.Border.Color}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Pressed.Foreground.Brush" Color="{StaticResource Pressed.Foreground.Color}" />
<!--#endregion-->
```

```
<!--#region FocusVisualButton-->
<Style x:Key="BtnFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle
                    Margin="2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                    StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                    StrokeThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!--#endregion-->
<!--#region DefaultBtn-->
<Style x:Key="DefaultBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource BtnFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,11,12,10" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="Fant" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica Arial sans-serif" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Background.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Foreground.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Border.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness=".9"
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="PART_Button"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="Common">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource MouseOver.Background.Color}" />
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource MouseOver.Border.Color}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource Pressed.Background.Color}" />
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource Pressed.Border.Color}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Normal" />
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="MouseOver">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Pressed">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Focused">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".6" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!--#endregion-->
```

Применение стиля:

```
<Button Content="Default Button" Style="{StaticResource DefaultBtn}" />
```

Для того чтобы не писать для каждой кнопки стиль можно задать унификацию так:

```
<!--#region Set DefaultBtn style as Default style for Button-->
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultBtn}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" />
<!--#endregion-->
```

Comment: Проект не запускается из за этой строчки  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" пишет что, Приложение перешло в состояние останова, но отсутствует код для вывода на экран, так как все потоки исполняли внешний код (как правило, системный код или код платформы).

Comment: @Sergey: Куда вы записали стили? Вообще должно быть все хорошо, сам проверял, т.к. стили были написаны мной.

Comment: Создал Словарь ресурсов назвал Button и Color и подключил эти стили через App.xaml

Comment: Дело в том что это работает в пустом проекте, а в том куда мне нужно внедрить эту функцию не работает.

Comment: @Sergey: Это довольно странно, т.к. проверил на существующем проекте, все хорошо отработало, ошибка где-то у вас.

Comment: @Sergey: попробуйте убрать словари ресурсов, и прямо как есть запишите в тег `Resources`, `app.xaml`, т.е. цвета, далее стиль без словарей. Возможно у вас в словаре кроется нечто странное :)

Comment: Может быть проблема в том что у меня в кнопке картинка?

Comment: @Sergey: Если картинка как контент, нет, если как фон, да, тут могут быть проблемы

Comment: Вроде нашёл ошибку, это из за того что кнопки находятся в стак панели, но почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

При применение стилей выше и возникновения ошибки связанной с Background Убедитесь что на кнопке присутствует кисть для Backgraund пусть даже и бесцветная. [image: Свойство кнопки]